# Node.js перестал работать бот после смены домена на https

Tags: node.js

Есть скрипт bot.js
Ранее он работал на сайте с доменом http://op-money.ru
Сейчас сайт изменил домен на https://nvutis.ru, после чего бот просто перестал работать. Я пробовал изменять все ссылки с op-money на nvutis, но это не помогло, в чем может быть проблема?

```js
var scribe = require('scribe-js')(),
    app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    requestify = require('requestify');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
server.listen(2020);

add_online();
setInterval(add_online, 60000);
activebots();


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 updateOnline();
 getDrops();
 
 socket.on('newDrop', function(id){
  requestify.post('http://op-money.ru/api/getGame', { id: id})
  .then(function (response) {
  data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  io.sockets.emit('nd', data.text);
  }, function (err) {
   console.log(err);
        });
  
 });
 
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        updateOnline();
    });
 
});
function updateOnline(){
 io.sockets.emit('updateonline', Number(Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).length) + Number(global.online));
    console.info('Connected ' + Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms).length + ' clients');
 
}


function getDrops(){
 requestify.post('http://op-money.ru/api/getdrops', {})
 .then(function (response) {
  data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  io.emit('welcomedrop', data.text);
  console.log("stats");
 }, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
 });
};

function activebots()
{
 console.log("\x1b[32m", "[NVBOT] Функция ботов сработала!");
 requestify.post('http://op-money.ru/api/playbot', {})
 .then(function (response) {
  data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  var time = data.time;
  console.log("\x1b[32m", "[NVBOT] Фейк-Игра сыграна! ID: "+data.game+" Время: "+ Number(data.time)+"мс");
  requestify.post('http://op-money.ru/api/getGame', { id: data.game})
  .then(function (response) {
  data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  io.sockets.emit('nd', data.text);
  
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    activebots();
  }, time);

  }, function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   setTimeout(activebots, 50000);
        });
  
  
 }, function (err) {
  console.log("\x1b[31m", "[NVBOT] Ошибка запроса");
  setTimeout(activebots, 50000);
 });
}

function add_online()
{
 requestify.post('http://op-money.ru/api/getonline', {})
 .then(function (response) {
  data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  global.online = data.online;
  console.log("\x1b[32m", "[NVBOT] Фейк онлайн обновлен! (+" + data.online + ")");
  updateOnline();
 }, function (err) {
  console.log("\x1b[31m", "[NVBOT] Ошибка получения фейкового онлайна");
 });
}
```

Comment: http на https пробовал?)

Comment: любой запрос с https На http - Будет по умолчанию заблокирован браузером. Посмотри ошибки в консоли

Comment: А вот тут нужно https писать? server = require('http').Server(app),